# Scales importing .stl file

Tags: import, dimensions, stl

I need to import a .stl in blender. First I changed the "Scale" in "Scene" to 0.01 (centimeters), then I chaged "Scale" in "Display" (N-sidebar) in 0.01 too. When I import the stl. file the object appears with dimensions larger than it should be. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I've read another posts but I don't understand what to do. I tried scaling the object (X = 0.01, Y = 0.01, Z = 0.01) but then the object becomes smaller.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Changing the scale in the scene settings only affects what happens when you work with units. The scale in Display only affects the size of the grid floor. And if you scale an object by 0.01 of course it becomes smaller, that's what scaling is for.

Comment: Yes, but I read that about scaling in another post. I want my object keep the original dimensions

Comment: The dimensions should not change when you import an STL file. What problem are you facing here?

Comment: Are you trying to scale the imported object to an absolute size?

Answer (score 8):

You should to know the scale used in the STL file, for example OpenSCAD uses millimeters for all, when you export your work from OpenSCAD to a STL file, the scale will be mm.

So you should configure the scale in the Blender importer to use 0.001 as scale, because, in Blender, if configured the world scale in the metric system, a unit is a meter.

Summarizing:

1. Configure the world units in Blender as Metric system.
2. Left the World scale in Blender as 1.000 (1 Blender's unit will be 1 meter)
3. When importing, select 0.001 as scale for the STL file. So 1 unit in the STL will be a Blender's unit * 0.001 converting the mm of the STL to meters.